# javascript the passed anonymous function does not change value of parameters

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

I used anonymous function as parameter in another function, and the anonymous function itself has parmeters also.When the another function is running, and the anonymous func does not work as I expected.I was coufused, can you help? The code is below:

```
function go(x, func){
  func(x);
  alert(x.x);
}

var x = {'x': 3};
go(x, function(x){x = {'x':99};});//actually it alert 3, not 99, x not change
go(x, function(x){x.x = 7;}); //it behaves normal, alert 7, not 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is x ?**
`var x = {'x': 3};`

x is variable which is a reference to the actual value of the object.

**First Scenario:**
`go(x, function(x){x = {'x':99};});//actually it alert 3, not 99, x not change`

When the function is invoked using `func(x);` **the value of reference is passed by value** Following activities happen

1. A new variable `x` is created
2. Assign the value of x (created in step 1) to global variable `x`,
   effectively x contains a reference of the global variable x.
3. Next, when you make any change to x like `x = {'x':99};` it will
   just create a new Object `{'x':99}` and assign the new reference of
   the new Object to x. Hence, x (step 1) is pointing to a new object,
   which has value of x as 99.
4. In next line `alert(x.x);` x is pointing to global object and since
       the global object x is not modified the value of `x.x` is still
       **3**.

**Second Scenario:**
`go(x, function(x){x.x = 7;}); //it behaves normal, alert 7, not 3`

First few steps are similar

1. A new variable `x` is created
2. Assign the value of x (created in step 1) to global variable `x`,
   effectively x contains a reference of the global variable x.
3. This statement `{x.x = 7;}` is actually a kind of dereference or you
   are trying to fetch the value of the global object `x` and then
   assigning a new value of 7 to the global object `x` property `x`. You are
   modifying the global object and not changing the reference of x to a new object as
   was done in the first scenario. So changes are reflected across the
   global object `x`.
4. Next, the statement `alert(x.x);` The x is the global object, *but
   in this case* the value of `x.x` (global) has been modified by the
   anonymous function.

Comment: Oh, I make the mistake（╯#-_-)╯╧═╧ ( ╯#-_-)╯┴—┴, reference  x itself is passed by value, and I try to modify a value.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is how JS interprets the codes
`x = { x: 99}` and `x.x = 7`
**The first code** means that you create completely new anonymous object `{x: 99}`, and then change the reference of the global variable `x` to this object.  Meanwhile **the second code** just gets the reference to the global variable `x` and change  it's property. That's it :)

Comment: Thanks!(•‾̑⌣‾̑•)✧˖°

Answer (score 0):

For explanations see above anwers. This is a fix to your problem:

```
function go(x, func){
  x=func(x)||x;
   alert(x.x);
 }

var x = {'x': 3};
go(x, function(x){return {'x':99};});//works now
go(x, function(x){x.x = 7;}); //it behaves normal, alert 7, not 3
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question:)